# How do I make an Http request from my server to another server in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 project that needs to retrieve data from another server (it is on the same domain).

Is there a way for the server to transmit (rather than the normal receive) of HTTP requests?

Comment: Typical Stackoverflow. Close action with no explanation why!